# Unable to get results of controller whilst using Join Annotations in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, join

I am new to hibernate and trying to implement join annotations of hibernate, but facing this weird issue. As I have attached pojos when I run my controller no output is seen but  a new row got populated in user_song_rel table as a foreign key to the song table.
In addition, value of that entry is null(in MySQL screenshot) despite there are entries in the song table corresponding to song_ids.
Please find attached schema of both tables.
Thanks in advance :)

**Schema Structure**

[image: Schema Structure]

User Song Mapping

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name="findUserSongByUserID",
            query="from UserSongRel usr where usr.user_id = :user_id"
            )
})

@Entity
@Table(name="user_song_rel")
public class UserSongRel {
    public UserSongRel() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int usr_id;
    private String user_id;
    private String song_id;
    private String song_src;
    private int song_state;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date add_date;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "song_id")
    private SongInfo songInfo;
```

Song

```
@Entity (name = "song_info")
public class SongInfo {
    @Id
    private String song_id;
    private String s_name;
    private String artist;
    private String album;
    private int duration;
    private Date rel_date;
    private int popularity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "songInfo")
    private List<UserSongRel> userSongRelList=new ArrayList<UserSongRel>();
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUserSongs/{uid}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces  = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUserSongs(@PathVariable String uid,
            HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
          SongInfo usr= songService.getUserSongs(uid);
          return ResponseEntity.ok().body(usr);


    }
```

DAO

```
    public SongInfo getUserSongs(String uid) {

        Session s = sf.getCurrentSession();
        UserSongRel songs=s.get(UserSongRel.class, 1);
        List<UserSongRel> songList =new ArrayList<UserSongRel>();
        songList.add(songs);
        return songList.get(0).getSongInfo();

    }
```

**Select query after running controller.**

[image: Select query after running controller]